# Drop database which has a "minus" in its name in Postgres

Tags: postgres-xl, drop-database

I've this database named `a-b` in postgres and I'm unable to delete it using this query `drop database "a-b";`. The double quotes were supposed to work but sadly, they didn't. I'm using Postgres-XL r1.3.

The error message I receive is:

> `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"`

Comment: Have you tried prepending backslash like a\-b?

Comment: What do you mean "sadly, they haven't"? Does that mean it produces the same error message?

Comment: sadly, they didn't work i mean

Comment: yes i've tried prepending backslash as well. and they too, didn't work :(

Comment: This **will** work in "plain" Postgres, so this is most probably a Postgres-XL problem. Looks like the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143887/how-can-i-drop-a-postgres-xl-database-that-has-its-name-starting-with-a-digit

Comment: Maybe you should try it from command line. I would suggest you to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7073852/1867076

Comment: well i tried it from the Postgres-XL (pgxc) as well and it still fails :( says PGXC dropdb 'a-b' -p 6100
dropdb: database removal failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"

Comment: Can't you wrap the database name in square braces?  i.e. DROP DATABASE [a-b];

Comment: says ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["

Comment: this is probably supposed to be a postgres-xl problem then. hope they'll figure it out.

Comment: You could try renaming it first perhaps? ALTER DATABASE "a-b" RENAME TO adashb;  Then follow up with a DROP DATABASE adashb;

Comment: worked like a charm! many thanks @SteveMatthews :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try renaming it first perhaps? ALTER DATABASE "a-b" RENAME TO adashb; Then follow up with a DROP DATABASE adashb;

Answer (score 1):

This bug is fixed in the latest Postgres-XL 9.5r1.4 release http://files.postgres-xl.org/documentation/release-xl-9-5r1.4.html